# What is the advantages of printf() (formatted print) over normal print()?

Tags: java

Basically i am a noob at programming but one of the first exercises we had was we had to use printf() which i found really difficult so i was wondering is there any real advantage to using printf() over print() with concatenation signs.

Comment: Here's a somewhat contrived example: `System.out.println(0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05);` and `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", 0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05);`

Comment: Now, for fun, you replicate the output of `System.out.printf("%20s %20s%n", "And", "Another");` and `System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s%n", "Just", "Because");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `printf()` you can do a lot of advanced formatting which `print()` can't do

[Check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf)